# Append into a table multiple inputs through javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a scenario which i have to use this way of appending lines into table
The javascript isn't accepting any input type='text' , for unknown reason,
If i put a normal text variable, it is working .I think there is a problem in single quotes / double quotes

```
  <?php
    for($counter=0;$row_work_entry=mysqli_fetch_array($run_work_entry);$counter++){
        $work_entry_days=$row_work_entry[0];
        $work_entry_type_id=$row_work_entry[1];
        $totalhours=date('h.i',strtotime($row_work_entry[2]));
        $name=$row_work_entry[3];
        $code=$row_work_entry[4];
        $workingdaystablelines.="<tr><td><input type='text'/></td><td>".$code."   </td><td>".$work_entry_days."</td><td>".$totalhours."</td></tr>";
     }

    ?>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
         var workingdaystablelines ='<?php echo $workingdaystablelines;?>';
         $('#worked_days_table').append(workingdaystablelines);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: what error you get? is there any logs?

Comment: Yes, of course there is a problem with the quotes. But why are you using JS for this in the first place, why do you not place the PHP output into the correct element _directly_?

Comment: the only reason I could imagine is if this table is 3rd party and generated elsewhere post doc ready. As for the initial question yes its the quotes. the `'` quote in Javascript is seen as an opening of a string and thus breaking your append

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php you need to escape the string in prep to inject into the HTML ie(`echo htmlspecialchars($workingdaystablelines, ENT_QUOTES);`)

Comment: Please share more details. How is this problem related to PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your code locally but single quotes gives me an error

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   var workingdaystablelines = "<?php echo $workingdaystablelines;?>"
   $('#worked_days_table').append(workingdaystablelines)
 })
```

You may use double qoutes instead

and also you may use [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to avoid xss attack

```
echo htmlspecialchars($workingdaystablelines,ENT_QUOTES);
```

Comment: have you tested it with double quotes? ... Because that will break too...